# error C2664: cannot convert from 'LPTSTR []' to 'LPCTSTR *'

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I use Visual Studio 2013 and I get the following error:

> error C2664: 'DWORD Options(int,LPCTSTR *,LPCTSTR,...)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'LPTSTR []' to 'LPCTSTR *' 54    1   ConsoleApplication3

This is the code:

```
DWORD Options(int argc, LPCTSTR argv[], LPCTSTR OptStr, ...){
    // Code
}
int _tmain(int argc, LPTSTR argv[]){
   iFirstFile = Options(argc, argv, _T("s"), &dashS, NULL);
   // Code 
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?
And explain why this error does occur?

Comment: use `Options(argc, const_cast<LPCTSTR*>(argv), _T("s"), &dashS, NULL);`

Comment: @RbMm: Why would you ever use a `const_cast` to **add** a `const` qualifier?

Comment: RbMm it no working. It error: Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ReportError referenced in function _main 
and error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: Do you understand the error message?

Comment: @zzZOsiroZzz - how this related to const_cast<LPCTSTR*>(argv) ?

Comment: @IInspectable - of course can and use `reinterpret_cast<LPCTSTR*>(argv)` or `(LPCTSTR*)(argv)` but from my look the `const_cast` most suitable by sense - `convert to a type that is identical except for the const, volatile, and __unaligned qualifiers and the result will refer to the original object`

Comment: um huh, It work, thanks you @RbMm

Comment: @RbMm: Adding a `const` qualifier is an implicit conversion. If you use a `const_cast` to add a `const` qualifier it has the same effect as not using any cast at all.

Comment: @IInspectable - if convert `T*` to `const T*` - yes. we not need explicit. but if convert `T**` to `const T**` already need. how minimum in my version of compiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***"And explain why this error does occur?"***

The reason behind this error can be found [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#constptrptr-conversion):
an implicit conversion *"... would let you silently and accidentally modify a const object **without a cast**..."*

***"Does anyone know how to fix it?"***

`LPCTSTR argv[]` is not a constant object, but an array of constant strings. The array itself may be modified (`argv[0] = 0;`).
Since the advice in the link above is to avoid casting (*"...please do not pointer-cast your way around that compile-time error message..."*), the simplest solution is to change the signature of `Options` (notice the added **const**):

```
DWORD Options(int argc, const LPCTSTR argv[], LPCTSTR OptStr, ...)
```